# Can I have multiple configure.ac files and what to do with AC_OUTPUT then?

Tags: projects-and-solutions, autotools, autoconf, automake

I have this directory structure:

- foo
- foo/libfoo - `libfoo` project
- foo/libfoo/src - sources
- foo/foo - `foo` project
- foo/foo/src - sources

There are two separate things that have to be build here, a libtool library (`libfoo`) and an executable (`foo`) using that library.

I could just place a `configure.ac` file into each `foo/libfoo` and `foo/foo` and everything would be fine.

However I would like to be able to build both projects at once, so I thought about placing an additional `configure.ac` into the top level `foo` directory.

Is this a good idea?

If yes, how would the `AC_OUTPUT` makro be used in such a case?

Does the top level `configure.ac` file generate all the `Makefile`s in the whole tree or are there separate `AC_OUTPUT` makros in the sub directories that each output there `Makefile`s?

Since both projects have different dependencies I would think the subdir ac files do the output of their makefiles?

Can the two projects in the sub dirs still be build separately in this case?

Comment: Try to run *autoscan*, it will scan all subdirs and generates a configure.scan, it is a good prototype to write your configure.ac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [`AC_CONFIG_SUBDIRS` macro](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.63/html_node/Subdirectories.html) that does what I want, it recurses into subdirs and executes the `configure.ac` files there.

The sub dir projects can still be build independently.

My `Makefile.am` only contains `SUBDIRS = libfoo foo` now.

The `configure.ac` file contains `AC_CONFIG_SUBDIRS=([libfoo foo])`.

Comment: if `foo` and `libfoo` are tightly coupled (e.g. released as one), you might find having three configure-scripts a bit of an overkill.